# JQuery not executing within a For loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im a JQuery noob trying to write a simple jQuery code to get a text to blink three times. My initial code was as follows:

```
$("#welcome").click(function () {
            var i = 1;
            while (++i < 10) {
                    $("#welcome").fadeOut("slow", function () { $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow"); })();
            }
        });
```

But since I probably meddled in forces I could not comprehend, the above code made the text blink only once. I read up on closures and got convinced that the below code could make a change. Unfortunately, it doesnt.

```
$("#welcome").click(function () {
        var i = 1;
        while (++i < 10) {
            (function (i) {
                $("#welcome").fadeOut("slow", function () { $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow"); })();
            })(i);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on here?

Comment: nothing to do with closure , but you have to give some time in between each call..

Comment: Ok, but, the statement, when executed once performs the animation once, as expected. But I tried giving the same thrice and it still works once. I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work, and not how to perform blink animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make use of the animation queue

```
var $welcome = $("#welcome").click(function () {
    var i = 1;
    //clear previous animations
    $welcome.stop(true, true);
    while (++i < 10) {
        $welcome.fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6fw9M/)

Comment: Thank you, but, I still need to understand why the above didn't work in a loop even though it worked fine once.

Comment: @MklRjv first there is a error, the `()` at the end of the `$("#welcome").fadeOut("slow", function () { $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow"); })();`

Comment: @MklRjv then have a look at the console logs created by http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6fw9M/2/

Comment: the `fadeOut()` are added to the queue first then after all fadeOut's fadeIns are added so they are nont in order

Answer (score 1):

Fading in and out takes some time, and you have to wait for your animation to be over before you can run the next one.

The provided answers solve your problem since jQuery is clever enough to bufferize your animation queue, but it may creates even more confusion for begginers, and also if you want to do something else between the fading animations, you can't rely on it anymore.

You then have to write your code on what is called an asynchronous recursive way (woah). Simply trying to understand that snippet may help you a lot with javascript general programming.

```js
function blink(nbBlinks) {
  // Only blink if the nbBlinks counter is not zero
  if(nbBlinks > 0) {
    $('#welcome').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      // Do stuff after the fade out animation
      $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Now we're done with that iteration, blink again
        blink(nbBlinks-1);
      })
    });
  }
}

// Launch our blinking function 10 times
blink(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/X5Qy3/

```
$("#welcome").click(function () {
      for (var x = 0; x < 3; x += 1) {
        $("#welcome").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#welcome").fadeIn("slow");
      }
});
```

Also, if you know how many times you want to do something. You should use a `For Loop`. `While Loops` are for when you don't know how many times you want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Set in queue

```
   $("#welcome").click(function () {
        var i = 1;
   //clear animations whcih are running at that time
    $(this).stop(true, true);
        while (++i < 10) {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use jQuery delay function inside a looping/iteration hence you have to user closures:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".click1").click(function () {
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        setTimeout(function(x) { 
            return function() { 
                $("#wrapper").fadeOut("slow", function () { $("#wrapper").fadeIn("slow"); })();
            }; 
        }(i), 1000*i);
    }
});
});

<div id="wrapper"></div><div class="click1">click</div>
```

You can later change the count how many times you want to blink the `<div>`.